# python googlemaps all possible distances between different locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps

```
schools=['GSGS','GSGL','JKG','JMG','MCGD','MANGD','SLSA','WHGR','WOG','GCG','LP', 
  'PGG', 'WVSG', 'ASGE','CZG', 'EAG','GI'] 

for i in range (1,17):
    gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='')
    distances = gmaps.distance_matrix((GSGS), (schools), mode="driving"['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
    print(distances)
```

The elements of the list are schools. I didn't want to make the list to long so I used these abbreviations. 
I want to get all the distances between "GSGS" and the schools in the list. I don't know what to write inside the second bracket.

```
distances = gmaps.distance_matrix((GSGS), (schools)
```

If I run it like that, it outputs this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/helpmecoding/PycharmProjects/untitled/distance.py", line 31, in 
<module>
distances = gmaps.distance_matrix((GSGS), (schools), mode="driving")['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
KeyError: 'distance'
```

I could do it one for one but thats not what I want. If I write another school from the list schools and delete the for loop it works fine.

I know I have to do a loop so that it cycles trough the list, but I don't know how to do it. Behind every variable for example "GSGS" is the address/location from the school. 
I deleted the key just for safety.

Answer (score 1):

My Dad helped me and we solved the problem. Now i have what i want :) Now i have to do a list with all distances between the schools. And if i got that i have to do the Dijkstra Algorithm to find the shortest route between them. Thanks for helping!

```
import googlemaps

GSGS = (address)
GSGL = (address)
.    .     .
.    .     .
.    .     .

schools = 
(GSGS,GSGL,JKG,JMG,MCGD,MANGD,SLSA,WHGR,WOG,GCG,LP,PGG,WVSG,ASGE,CZG,EAG,GI)

school_names = ("GSGS","GSGL","JKG","JMG","MCGD","MANGD","SLSA","WHGR","WOG","GCG","LP","PGG","WVSG","ASGE","CZG","EAG","GI")

school_distances = ()
for g in range(0,len(schools)):
n = 0
    for i in schools:
        gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='TOPSECRET')
        distances = gmaps.distance_matrix(schools[g], i)['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
    if school_names[g] != school_names[n]:
        print(school_names[g] + " - " + school_names[n] + " " + distances)
    else:
        print(school_names[g] + " - " + school_names[n] + " " + "0 km")
    n = n + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is sometimes difficult to know what is going on when you use a third-party api. Though I am not a proponent of reinventing the wheel sometimes it is necessary to get a full picture of what is going on. So, I recommend giving it a shot building your own api endpoint request call and see if that works.

```
import requests

schools = ['GSGS','GSGL','JKG','JMG','MCGD','MANGD','SLSA','WHGR','WOG','GCG','LP','PGG', 'WVSG', 'ASGE','CZG', 'EAG','GI']

def gmap_dist(apikey, origins, destinations, **kwargs):
    units = kwargs.get("units", "imperial")
    mode = kwargs.get("mode", "driving")
    baseurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"
    urlargs = {"key": apikey, "units": units, "origins": origins, "destinations": destinations, "mode": mode}
    req = requests.get(baseurl, params=urlargs)
    data = req.json()

    print(data)

    # do this for each key and index pair until you 
    # find the one causing the problem if it 
    # is not immediately evident from the whole data print
    print(data["rows"])
    print(rows[0])


    # Check if there are elements
    try:
       distances = data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError("No elements found")
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError("API Request Error. No response returned")
    else:
        return distances
```

Also as a general rule of thumb it is good to have a test case to make sure things are working as they should before testing the whole list,

```
#test case
try:
    test = gmap_dist(apikey="", units="imperial", origins="GSGS", destinations="GSGL", mode="driving")
except Exception as err:
    raise Exception(err)
else:
    dists = gmap_dist(apikey="", units="imperial", origins="GSGS", destinations=schools, mode="driving")
    print(dists)
```

Lastly, if you are testing the distance from "GSGS" to other schools, then you might want to get it out of your list of schools as the distance will be 0.

Now, I suspect that the reason you are getting this exception is because there are no json elements returned. Probably, because one of your parameters was improperly formatted.

If this function returns a KeyError still. Check the address spelling and make sure your apikey is valid. Although if it was the Apikey I would expect they would not bother to give you even empty results.

Hope this helps. Comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you but still Errors. `distances = data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']
IndexError: list index out of range` `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:raise IndexError("API Request Error. No response returned")
IndexError: API Request Error. No response returned`

Comment: I just need a way to fix this loop. But i dont know how :(

Comment: Are you still looping? The googlemaps matrix distance end point accepts multiple locations in one request. just leave my function as is. As far as the index error - try setting different points where the output is printed to make sure it is working. I will update the response to reflect this. Lastly, try one location as a test then work from the loop. It will help if you have a api request limit.

Comment: it would be really nice if don't have to do all routes manually by repeating and changing the program over and over again.  `schools=['GSGS','GSGL','JKG','JMG','MCGD','MANGD','SLSA','WHGR','WOG','GCG','LP', 
  'PGG', 'WVSG', 'ASGE','CZG', 'EAG','GI'] 

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='')distances = gmaps.distance_matrix((GSGS), (GSGL), mode="driving"['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
    print(distances)`

Comment: You dont have to do it individually. The API url will accept an encoded list which requests does for you. I just fixed the function, added 's' to 'origin' parameter. read the developer docs. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixRequests

Comment: Trust me it happens to the best of us. The goal is not to make the same mistakes twice. Good luck.